# Conversion between Int and fractional values

Tags: haskell, floating

I am programming in Haskell and I am having trouble with the following code:

```
exactRootList :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
exactRootList ini end = 
      [x | x<-[ini .. end],  (floor (sqrt x)) == (ceiling (sqrt x))]
```

Then, when I execute:

```
> hugs myprogram.hs
```

I get

```
Error Instances of (Floating Int, RealFrac Int) required for definition of exactRootList
```

I do not understand this error.

My program should show a list of numbers that have exact root as 4 or 9, on the interval [a, b] where a and b are the two params of the function.
Example:

```
exactRootList 1 10
```

It must return

```
1 4 9
```

Because between 1 and 10 only 1, 4 and 9 have exact root.

Greetings!

Answer (score 6):

If you look at the type of `sqrt` you see it only works on types that are an instance of `Floating`:

```
> :t sqrt
sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a
```

As you probably know, `Int` is not a floating point value.  You need to convert your ints (the variable `x`) using `fromIntegral`:

```
[x | x<-[ini .. end],  let a = fromIntegral x
                       in (floor (sqrt a)) == (ceiling (sqrt a))]
```